# get price from json data using php and regex

Tags: php, json, regex

I'm trying to extract the price from a json output using php.

The price is listed as `"price": "49.00"`, I understand I need to use preg_match, but I'm having trouble with the regex (possibly)

Would `preg_match` also be the best function to use when looking for `"price": "49.00"`?

The code can be found here: https://pastebin.com/BCxh1nmT

Comment: Why not parse the JSON and pull the value?

Comment: Please share json output

Comment: I've just added the code to the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $var = json_decode ($output, true);
```

will produce $var array with values from your JSON. Then use it as usual array to get needed information like:

```
 print $var["price"];
```